# Why is hyper-v called a type-1 hypervisor?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, hypervisor

I have got a few related questions in this context.

1. Why is hyper-v called a type-1 hypervisor? At least on Windows 10 Pro, hyper-v clear runs on top of windows 10. So how does it (hyper-v) have access to bare metal without going through windows?
2. OK, for a moment, though I still don't know the reasons - I will agree that hyper-v is a type-1 hypervisor. Then what about windows 10 pro, which comes with hyper-v. When Hyper-V is enabled, does the base windows 10 pro run on top of hyper-v and if so, does not it's performance gets compromised?

Comment: Windows runs _in_ Hyper-V. It's virtualized too.

Comment: @gronostaj just a confirmation. By default on windows 10 pro, `hyper-v` is not enabled/installed right? So once it's enabled, windows 10 pro will run a virtual os. Is that right?

Comment: That's correct. Btw, you can verify that Windows is indeed virtualized in Hyper-V by searching this very website for Virtualbox and VMware issues, because they will refuse to run in Windows with Hyper-V enabled. (At least they used to, maybe Hyper-V supports nested virtualization now.)

Answer (score 4):

Hyper-V is a type 1 hypervisor.  In your case Windows 10 is running in a "special VM," or parent partition versus the other VMs (child partitions) you have. Here's a good illustration from Wikipedia.
[image: By Terendo - Own work, Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=9440429]

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hyper-V.png

When you enable Hyper-V the Windows 10 OS gets moved off the hardware to the Parent Partition.  However, the parent partition still has direct access to the physical hardware where the child partitions do not.